# Formatting problems with C3.js

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

I have problems with a visualisation I'm creating with C3.js.

1. The top and side edges of my scatter chart are cut off (probably because I'm changing the radius of the bubbles, but I don't think that should be a problem. I've tried giving padding, but no use.
2. When you mouseover the bubbles, more data about it appears in a donut chart below. When you mouseout, the pie chart legend doesn't disappear.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g6z60jh/2/) I created.

```
var chart3 = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart1',
  padding: {
    left: 150,
    right: 150
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['Posts', 666, 674, 919, 2300, 1200, 961]
    ],
    type: 'scatter',
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March']
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`c3.js` is very limited in terms of customization (comparing with other frameworks). It is not problem of bubbles being cut, I think it is an issue of the framework itself.

To solve your second problem:
`document.getElementById("chart2").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: Thanks. Which alternative would you suggest? Also, the fix you have given doesn't really work -- the legend still stays after mouse out.